# How to add custom http header to google big query client in c#

Tags: c#, google-bigquery, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to add a custom header to google bigquery client in below way, some reasons it is not working. Can someone suggest me how I can add custom header to google bigquery client.

Below is my sample code:

```cs
var gClient = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId, credential);
gClient.Service.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("test", "this is default header");
var results = gClient.ExecuteQuery(query, null);
```

With above code, I can see that the custom header 'test' is added to the httpclient, but when gClient executes the query, I don't see this custom header.

I am using the fiddler to monitor the traffic from my machine. In fiddler, the I can see that there are two calls are made.
i. oauth authentication
ii. bigquery execution

In both of the messages I don't see the default http header 'test'.

I also tried, `gClient.Service.HttpClientInitializer.Initialize()` to initialize the httpclient, but didn't work.

```cs
var gClient = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId, credential);
ConfigurableHttpClient httpClient = new ConfigurableHttpClient(new ConfigurableMessageHandler(new CustomMessageHandler()), true);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("xxxxx", "yyyyyyy");
gClient.Service.HttpClientInitializer.Initialize(httpClient);
```

In this case also, it is same problem... the default header is not part of the httprequest.

Can someone help me to solve this issue...?

FYI... we are intercepting all outbound calls using a proxy and based on this custom http header we need to take decision whether to allow outbound call or not. So, we would like to inject it at the service side and verify this custom header in the proxy.

As explained above, I have tried adding the `DefaultRequestHeaders` to the httpclient, but it is not working.

Also, I have tried `httpclient.MessageHandler.AddExecuteInterceptor()`. but still didn't work.

My question... can we inject a default httpclient for all outbound calls in c#? especially for google big queries.

Comment: I've just tried your first piece of code, also using Fiddler, and the header *is* present (as I'd expect). I wouldn't expect it to be on the Auth call, btw. If you need it to be present for the auth call as well, that's probably worth a separate question as they'd use different HTTP clients.