# Is it possible to use Polly (for auto retrying) with Google BigQuery client for .NET?

Tags: c#, google-bigquery, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic

I've got some code that inserts data up to Google BigQuery. works great. Until I needed to upload about 10mil of rows/items to BigQuery. At randome times I get SSL cert errors. Fine / whatever.

So I thought: can we use POLLY to handle this randomness?

I'm just not sure if Google BigQuery has any ability for this? does it / is this possible?

Here's some sample code which i'm using to push data up (in case this might help/inspire):

```
var client = await BigQueryClient.CreateAsync(_projectId, _googleCredential);

...

var result = await client.InsertRowsAsync(destinationTable, rows, null, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Can you split your insert into lets say 10 chuncks? (1 mil records / insert request) I'm not familiar with GCP but I would be really surprised if the BQ client does not have built-in support for retry.

Comment: Please also bear in mind that not all operation failures are retriable. Retrying an insert can typically results in unwanted duplicates. If that's acceptable or BQ insert is implemented in an idempotent way then you are good to go. Otherwise you have to deal with duplicates on query side if your domains allows that.

Comment: good point about the duplicates. But yes, I've already got measures in place for that. So it's really about the intermittent networking issues that pop up (which is aways this weird SSL error). That said, If the retries via Polly also fail after .. say .. 3 or 5 hardcoded retries then i'm kewl with _that_ exception then getting thrown. It's just to prevent the dicky little odd 1 every 5 or 10 mins etc. Also, i'm already batching in batches of 1000. working great!

Comment: Polly's retry can be setup in a way to perform retry attempts (indefinitely) until the operation succeeds. Would that be helpful for your problem?

Comment: for me, nope - I never do indefinitely in case it's not an "intermittent" issue. I usually do fall back with a fixed number of retries.

Comment: Sorry I'm lost. So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: is it possible to provide an HttpClient instance that is wired up to polly or something, to the BigQuery client?

Comment: As I said I'm not a familiar with BigQuery but based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75225102/how-to-add-custom-http-header-to-google-big-query-client-in-c-sharp) it seems like you can access the underlying `HttpClient` or even you can register a `IConfigurableHttpClientInitializer`.